# Python/jython join two lists in list of lists with condition

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that was used for fortran and the line limit on the text file is limited to 80 characters. I am attempting to parse it in python.

There are characteristic tables for different projects and within those tables there are tables of tables.  Different sites may have all or none of the data shown below.

```
1PROGRAM                                          MYPRJ PROJECT CHARACTERISTIC DATA                           PROJECT
    11/22/00                                               MASTER FILE                                  NO     NAME       REV
                                                                                                         1   PROJ          


 DATA1                   7000.0  uni
 DATA2                  -5000.0  uni
 DATA3                          12000.0  uni
 DATA4                    3000.  uni



 TBL1 TITLE            
   VAL1 UNI            0.0    10000.0    30000.0    60000.0   100000.0   300000.0
   VAL2 UNI             1858.0     1863.4     1870.3     1876.0     1882.0     1900.0


 TBL2 TITLE         
   VAL1 UNI         6542.0     1156.7     3697.1     4569.3     9564.9     5698.0     9874.7     3654.7     3698.8     2135.0
                        7894.0     5568.0     7845.3     3657.7
   VAL2 UNI            0.0    18300.0    22500.0    99900.0    36900.0    69800.0    58700.0    63520.0    69870.0    55260.0
                       61100.0   127900.0   166600.0   236900.0


 TBL3 TITLE
   VAL1 UNI            -4876.9    -5642.3    -1225.7        9.0      375.4      322.0     8860.8     1568.1     4567.0     6953.0
                        6578.1     1236.7     3970.0     5632.3     3265.1     3698.1     1236.2     1236.4     7000.0
   VAL2 UNI             3265.1     1236.7     5632.3     2394.1     2405.0     1876.0     7845.3     2420.0     5568.0     2548.0
                        5632.3     3265.1     2694.1     5568.0     2455.0     5632.3     1863.4     2670.0     2565.0
```

I have been reading this in by

```
f = open("file.asc")  
f = [line.replace('\n','').strip() for line in f]
```

The difficulty I have been having is with the different sized tables, such as TBL1, and TBL2.  TBL1 is small and all values are contained on a single line.  TBL2 and TBL3 the values are longer than the 80 character limit and extend to the next line.  Therefore in my list of lists TBL2 VAL1 is broken up into two lists.

```
TBL1 = [['TBL1 TITLE'], ['VAL1 UNI', '0.0', '10000.0', '30000.0', '60000.0', '100000.0', '300000.0'],['VAL2 UNI','1858.0', '1863.4', '1870.3', '1876.0', '1882.0', '1900.0']]
TBL2 = [[['TBL2 TITLE'],['VAL1 UNI', '6542.0', '1156.7','3697.1', '4569.3', '9564.9', '5698.0', '9874.7', '3654.7', '3698.8', '2135.0'], ['7894.0', '5568.0', '7845.3', '3657.7'], ['VAL2 UNI', '0.0', '18300.0', '22500.0', '99900.0', '36900.0', '69800.0', '58700.0', '63520.0', '69870.0', '55260.0'],['61100.0', '127900.0', '166600.0', '236900.0']]]
```

I have left out TBL3 for brevity

What I want is

```
TBL1 = [['TBL1 TITLE'], ['VAL1 UNI', '0.0', '10000.0', '30000.0', '60000.0', '100000.0', '300000.0'],['VAL2 UNI','1858.0', '1863.4', '1870.3', '1876.0', '1882.0', '1900.0']]
TBL2 = [[['TBL2 TITLE'],['VAL1 UNI', '6542.0', '1156.7','3697.1', '4569.3', '9564.9', '5698.0', '9874.7', '3654.7', '3698.8', '2135.0','7894.0', '5568.0', '7845.3', '3657.7'], ['VAL2 UNI', '0.0', '18300.0', '22500.0', '99900.0', '36900.0', '69800.0', '58700.0', '63520.0', '69870.0', '55260.0','61100.0', '127900.0', '166600.0', '236900.0']]]
```

Comment: What does your text file look like?  It may be easier to fix this when you're reading it in vs after you've done `a little cleaning`.

Comment: @Gerrat I edited the above.  It is a text file restricted to 80 character lines, there are other parts of the file that I am parsing as well so I don't know if that will be an obstacle when trying to parse when pulling data in.

Comment: @JeffTilton share how you are reading the file.

Comment: In your example, the line of data provided does not contain either 'a', nor 'b' or 24.5 ...  or any of the data provided in ```list1``` or ```list2```.

Comment: @JeffTilton share the full code in the question itself, not as a comment. use edit.

Comment: How do you know it should be a new list? Does the first element always `a`, `b` or could it be `a23`, `b2` etc? Do other elements except the first one contain letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If letters mean the start of a new list, you can do something like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy                   # use deepcopy to isolate the result from the 
                                            # input list so that the original list will not
                                            # be modified
def combine(lst):
    new_list = []
    for s in lst:
        if s[0].isalpha():                   # if the first element contains only letters
            new_list.append(deepcopy(s))     # create a new list in the result
        else:
            new_list[-1].extend(deepcopy(s)) # otherwise append it to the last element 
                                             # in the result    ​
    return new_list
​
combine(list1)

#[['title'],
# ['a', '-453.0', '-2913.0', '2983.9', '3476.7', '3970.0'],
# ['b', '23.9', '23.3', '35.0', '40.3', '24.5', '24.2', '24.7', '240.8']]

combine(list2)

# [['title'], ['c', '0.0', '100.0', '300.0'], ['d', '188.0']]
```

---

A different strategy is to check if the first element of each sub list can be converted to float, if it can, then this should be an extension of the last list, otherwise, it should be a new list:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def combine(lst):
    new_list = []
    for s in lst:
        try:
            float(s[0])
            new_list[-1].extend(deepcopy(s))
        except ValueError:
            new_list.append(deepcopy(s))
​
    return new_list

combine(list1)

#[['title'],
# ['a', '-453.0', '-2913.0', '2983.9', '3476.7', '3970.0'],
# ['b', '23.9', '23.3', '35.0', '40.3', '24.5', '24.2', '24.7', '240.8']]

combine(list2)

# [['title'], ['c', '0.0', '100.0', '300.0'], ['d', '188.0']]
```

Comment: The first approach gave me an out of index error.  The second approach is what I had been trying for, but it wasn't quite working out, your did.

Comment: Your `TBL2` is a three layer lists. You need to call it as `combine(TBL2[0])`. But that would make it inconsistent with `TBL1`.